# Python Selenium print text

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

There is such HTML code on the page, I need to get its text for check, or rather **740** using Selenium.

```
<button data-v-3630a784="" class="currency-btn mr10"><div data-v-3630a784="" class="progress"><div data-v-3630a784="" class="progress-bg anim" style="transform: scaleX(0.458333);"></div></div> <div data-v-3630a784="" class="num flex align-center icon-mana">740</div> <!----></button>
```

Comment: OK, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the text ***740*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='currency-btn'] div.num.flex.align-center.icon-mana").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'currency-btn')]//div[@class='num flex align-center icon-mana']").text)
  ```

---

To extract the text ***740*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='currency-btn'] div.num.flex.align-center.icon-mana"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'currency-btn')]//div[@class='num flex align-center icon-mana']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)